# Add day to subset of datetime column pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime

Somehow my logic is not working to simply add a day to a datetime column in my dataframe.
What am I missing?

```
df_sales.loc[df_sales.year_week == '2018-12-31']['year_week'] = df_sales['year_week'] + pd.Timedelta(days=1)
```

This piece of code returns the exact same values as I have subsetted the dataset on. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem you set slice, so need replace`][` to `,` only.

For better explanation check [`evaluation order matters`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#evaluation-order-matters):

```
df_sales.loc[df_sales.year_week == '2018-12-31', 'year_week'] = df_sales['year_week'] + pd.Timedelta(days=1)
```